# Unable to upload video to localhost

Tags: php, html, post, video, upload

I work in a PHP - HTML project, and I want to upload some files into a directory. The problem is that the code works fine, and I checked it for *.doc, *pdf, *.txt file types. However, I need to upload videos as well. When I try to do so, the upload is unsuccessful. What can I do? Is is a matter of file size? I tried to upload videos of size about 5Mb and the problem remains: After using var_dump() I understood that in the nextForm the $_POST['submit'] condition is false.

```
<form action='nextForm.php' method = 'post'  enctype= 'multipart/form-data' > 
file: <input type='file' name = 'upload' >
<p> <br> </p>
<input type='submit' name = 'submit' value ='upload it!' >
</form>
```

Comment: Do post some code and check upload limit, It's 2MB by default

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the value of upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in your php.ini .

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did it. By default the values were: post_max_size = 8M and I changed it to 80M. Also , the value upload_max_filesize was by default 128M so no need to change it. However, my video size is about 30Mb and I still can not upload it.